# Getting the implicitly deleted error when using a struct

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I'm getting this error:

```
<source>:48:32: error: use of deleted function 'FPTask_sim::Data_T::Data_T()'
   48 | FPTask_sim::Data_T FPTask_sim::_data;
      |                                ^~~~~
<source>:40:9: note: 'FPTask_sim::Data_T::Data_T()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   40 |       } Data_T;
      |         ^~~~~~
```

You can recreate the error using stripped version of my code:

(NOTE: comment the "#define BREAK_EVERYTHING" and the code will compile)

```
#define BREAK_EVERYTHING

namespace tinyfsm
{
    struct Event {};
}


namespace EventConsts
{
    struct EventCode_T  {};
    struct Event_T      {};

   struct EventStruct_T : tinyfsm::Event
    {
    #ifdef BREAK_EVERYTHING
        EventStruct_T(const Event_T& Event);           
    #else
        struct Event { };
    #endif
    };
}


class FPTask_sim
{
   public:
        FPTask_sim();
         
      typedef struct
      {
         tinyfsm::Event ARG_react_01_unused_arg01;

         EventConsts::EventStruct_T ARG_react_02_unused_arg01;          // These lines seem to be causing the issue
         EventConsts::EventStruct_T ARG_dispatch_e;                     // These lines seem to be causing the issue
      } Data_T;

      static Data_T _data;
      static Data_T _call_data;
};



FPTask_sim::Data_T FPTask_sim::_data;

int main()
{
    bool exampleVariable;
}
```

I'm thinking this is being caused by the

```
EventStruct_T(const Event_T& Event);
```

line, specifically because its being passed by reference and the overall object "_data" is static. Not sure how to fix this though.

Thanks!

---

EDITS:

Sorry, forgot to include the constructor that is in it already.
It looks like it just copies the Event_T obj to EventStruct_T.
If Im understanding what you are saying, I need to either give values when declaring the object or add in the blank default constructor. Right?

```
#define BREAK_EVERYTHING

namespace tinyfsm
{
    struct Event {};
}

namespace EventConsts
{
    struct Event_T      {bool a;};                

   struct EventStruct_T : tinyfsm::Event
    {
        bool a;
    #ifdef BREAK_EVERYTHING
        //EventStruct_T(){}                            // New default constructor? 
        EventStruct_T() = default;                     // Answer provided by user17732522
        EventStruct_T(const Event_T& Event);           
    #else
        struct Event { };
    #endif
    };
}


class FPTask_sim
{
   public:
        FPTask_sim();
         
      typedef struct
      {
         tinyfsm::Event ARG_react_01_unused_arg01;

         EventConsts::EventStruct_T ARG_react_02_unused_arg01;          // These lines seem to be causing the issue
         EventConsts::EventStruct_T ARG_dispatch_e;                     // These lines seem to be causing the issue
      } Data_T;

      static Data_T _data;
      static Data_T _call_data;
};



FPTask_sim::Data_T FPTask_sim::_data;

int main()
{
    bool exampleVariable;
}
```

```
// Current constructor in separate file
EventConsts::EventStruct_T::EventStruct_T(const EventConsts::Event_T& Event) :        
      a(Event.a),
{}
```

Comment: `typedef struct { /*...*/ } Data_T;` is an odd thing to do in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare any constructor for a class, then the default constructor (constructor not requiring any argument) will not be declared implicitly.

So then there is no constructor to construct e.g. `FPTask_sim::_data.ARG_react_02_unused_arg01` when you are trying to initialize it without constructor argument in `FPTask_sim::Data_T FPTask_sim::_data;`.

Either provide arguments to the initializer of `FPTask_sim::_data` so that `FPTask_sim::_data.ARG_react_02_unused_arg01` and the other are given arguments from which they can be constructed, give them default-initializers in the definition of `EventStruct_T` or define a default constructor for `EventStruct_T` yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to not provide arguments? There are a lot of them (Data_T and even EventStruct_T have multi lvl inheritance with many variables per lvl). I tried commenting out the empty default constructors in the code hoping the compiler would generate one, but didn't seem to help.

Comment: Or is there a way to get around this by use of pointers vs reference? I was messing around with that and got it to stop giving the implicitly deleted error, but started going down a rabbit hole of other changes so figured I'd check if there was a simple solution.

Comment: @Grant I don't quite understand. The problem is that there is no default constructor declared in the code you are showing. If you want to have a `EventStruct_T(const Event_T& Event);` constructor but still be able to construct an object of that class without providing an argument, then you simply have to give it a default constructor as well.

Comment: @Grant - You **are** allowed to have more than one constructor for a class, like one with parameters and one without.

Comment: @Grant In what storage you are creating the objects or how you are referring to them is completely irrelevant. Pointers or references don't change anything about this.

Comment: ok thanks. I just changed the original post to include the constructor that is already there. So I need to give it values when declaring an obj or add the blank default constructor right?

Comment: @Grant Yes, but you might want to default it instead of defining it yourself to make sure it behaves the same way as the implicit one would: `EventStruct_T() = default;`. That guarantees that initialization of the `EventStruct_T` with `()` or `{}` will zero the `bool` member. If you define the constructor yourself as empty, it will never initialize the member. You should manually initialize it always to zero in the constructor in that case. This guarantees that the member is _always_ initialized to zero even for default-initialization without initializer as you are using in your example.

Comment: Although in your example the object is a global variable with static storage duration, so it is zero-initialized no matter what. The zero-initialization question arises only for non-static storage duration objects.